# Is Set Difference the Relative Complement of the Subset Operator?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been writing my own notes on set theory and came across the relationship as the title states:

[image]

I have a feeling this is incorrect, am I misinterpreting the implication in the set builder definition? Thanks.

Comment: [Relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) $A \setminus B$ is $(A \cap B^c)$

Comment: Applying De Morgan to it we have $(A \setminus B)^c= A^c \cup B$

Comment: But the conclusion does not make much sense... $A \subseteq B$ is a statement, while $(A \setminus B)^c$ is a set (an object).

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ is a placeholder for the predicate $[\forall x, (x\notin A \lor x\in B)]$. On the other hand $T=\{x\,:\, (x\notin A)\lor (x\in B)\}$ is a placeholder for the predicate $$[\forall x,(((x\notin A\lor x\in B)\land x\in T)\lor (\neg (x\notin A\lor x\in B)\land x\notin T))]$$

Comment: The error arises from the first line: it is not *equality* (between sets) but a bi-conditional $\leftrightarrow$. The definition of set inclusion must be: $A \subseteq B \leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah I see, I was incorrectly equating an object to a logical statement

Comment: $A \subseteq B \iff (A\setminus  B)=\emptyset \iff (A\setminus  B)^c=\Omega$

Comment: I think we can say that if $U$ is the universal set that:  $A\subset B \iff A^c\cup B = U \iff A\setminus B = \emptyset \iff (A\setminus B)^c = U$. ( In my precaffienated haze that seems fine.)  But your notation abuse of comparing statements about sets with sets themselves with definitions of sets make your argument practically unreadable and nearly incomprehensible.  Likewise the title "Is Set Difference the Relative Complement of Subset" is hard to parse. If you mean "Is the set difference of a superset to a subset, the relative complement of a subset to a superset" the answer is yes.